Berry phases in closed timelike curves
Does anyone know what the physical significance of a Berry phase induced by parallel transport around a closed timelike curve would be? There is a preprint from 1994 describing that parallel transport operators undergo a phase transformation in CTCs. What does this mean?

Physical systems can't move along spacelike curves whether they are closed or not, so a phase along such a path means nothing.

Ah, yes. Agreed.

The "though experiment" interpretation of this is that you could detect the presence of particles that had gone around the CTC by looking for this phase if you did an interference experiment between control particles you knew had not gone around the curve, and test particles that may or may not have. However, as alanf says, CTCs are almost certainly not physical, so this thought experiment is probably not relevant for any real experiment in reality.

Well it is still useful for theoretical endeavors, regardless of experimental promise. Specifically, in the Kerr-Newman spacetime. Assuming they are indeed real, what is the difference between a regular Berry phase we all know and love, versus a CTC Berry phase. It would be interesting if one could make the connection with Geroch's theorem regarding spacetime topology change. Further, recent research is suggesting that Berry phases are related to topological wormholes in AdS/CFT https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11717.

Additionally, if there is indeed a phase transformation for state vectors evolving adiabatically in CTCs, how in the world does this affect measurement?
